# How to compare a form field with db values using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

Hi I m using this code  
 and recherche is the name of an input in the form   The problem is that Am tryin to make a search  using jsp jstl servlet
this is some of  my jstl code

```
    <c:forEach items="${offreRecherche}" var="o" >
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${o.type==recherche}">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${o.idOffre}"/></td>
    <td>${o.nameOffre}</td>
     <td>${o.specialite}</td>
     <td>${o.adresse}</td>
      <td>${o.region}</td>
        <td>${o.etat}</td>
        <td>${o.type}</td>
   </tr>
  </c:when>
```

Would u help me plz

Comment: `<c:when test="${o.type eq param.recherche}">` assuming `recherche` is a name of an input field inside a form. (I however, failed to understand the question thoroughly).

Comment: actually the way u answered me is what I m lookin for  thank u but I dont now why it didn t help me :( I will show u the code below of all my form and try to help me plz to find the error coz the search is not workin for  me